# How to format long text file with spaces?

Tags: excel, text

I have a .txt file that contains text that is formatted like so:

```
Neque porro, quisquam est qui 
 dolorem ipsum quia, dolor (sit amet)
 consectetur, adipisci velit,Lorem Ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
 tempor ipsum quia, minim (sit minim)
 consectetur, adipisci velit,Lorem Ipsum
```

There are multiple text items like this. I wish to make it so that they are all one liners each so I can paste them into excel like so

```
Neque porro, quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia, dolor (sit amet) consectetur, adipisci velit, Lorem Ipsum

dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit tempor ipsum quia, minim (sit minim) consectetur, adipisci velit,Lorem Ipsum
```

Would there be any way to do this for files with a lot of text that are like this?

Comment: What tool do you have to perform this task? You can try for example Notepad++ (windows only) that allows find and replace with regular expressions.

Comment: @DavidLeal Im fine with any tool that can get the job done, but I am using Windows

Comment: then check this, you may find some ideas for your real case: [Using regex to find and replace in Notepad++](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2020/using-regex-to-find-and-replace-text-in-notepad/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did want to use Excel (as your question indicates) this formula work if you had all text in a single cell

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)&" "," "),char(10),REPT(char(10),2))
```

[image]